# Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges. If it converges find the limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a_{n+1}}$

where:

$a_1>0$ and $a_2>0$.

I can't seem to solve this question and basically I've gotten nowhere. Please help.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I would start with the easy part. Assume that the limit exists and then take the limit of the equation.

Comment: @Severin Schraven. Ok, doing so i got the limit to be either 0 or 4, but since a_1 and a_2 must be > 0, the limit is 4. Now the problem is how do i prove that it converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$a_{n+2}\ge a_{n+1}^{1/2}\ge \ldots \ge a_2^{1/2^n}$$
Therefore $a_{n+2}\ge {1/2}$ for $n$ large enough. Then
$$a_{n+4}\ge 2\cdot 2^{-1/2}=2^{1/2}>1$$
Hence $a_n\ge 1$ for $n\ge n_0.$ For such $n$ we have
$$|a_{n+2}-4|\le |a_{n+1}^{1/2}-2| +|a_{n}^{1/2}-2|
\\
={|a_{n+1}-4|\over a_{n+1}^{1/2}+2}+{|a_{n}-4|\over a_{n}^{1/2}+2}\le {2\over 3}\max\{|a_{n+1}-4|,|a_{n}-4|\}
$$
Let $r:=\max\{|a_{n_0}-4|,|a_{n_0+1}-4|\}.$ Then
$$|a_{n_0+2}-4|\le {2\over 3}r,\quad |a_{n_0+3}-4|\le {2\over 3}r$$
By iterating $k$ times we get
$$|a_{n_0+2k}-4|\le {2^k\over 3^k}r,\qquad |a_{n_0+2k+1}-4|\le {2^k\over 3^k}r$$
Thus $$\lim_ka_{n_0+2k}=\lim_ka_{n_0+2k+1}=4,$$ hence $\lim_n a_n=4.$

Comment: |an+1−4|a1/2n+1+2+|an−4|a1/2n+2≤23max{|an+1−4|,|an−4|}  How did we get here from the last line? Namely where did the 2/3 come from?

Comment: Because the denominators as at least $3$ and there are two summands.